# Cannot add foreign key constraint on mysql-workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a table through mysql workbench. I am getting the following error :-

Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint SQL Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `propman`.`imageadassociation` (
  `ImageId` INT NOT NULL,
  `AdId` INT NOT NULL,
  INDEX `imageId_adassociation_idx` (`ImageId` ASC),
  INDEX `adId_adassociation_idx` (`AdId` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `imageId_adassociation`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ImageId`)
    REFERENCES `propman`.`imagelocation` (`ImageId`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `adId_adassociation`
    FOREIGN KEY (`AdId`)
    REFERENCES `propman`.`advertisement` (`AdId`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

The imageLocation table create state statement is as follows :-

```
CREATE TABLE `imagelocation` (
  `ImageId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ImageLocationcol` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The advertisement tables create statement is as follows :-

```
CREATE TABLE `advertisement` (
  `AdId` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PropertyId` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `AdTemplateId` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `ValidFrom` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ValidTo` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AdId`),
  KEY `AdTemplateId` (`AdTemplateId`),
  CONSTRAINT `advertisement_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`AdTemplateId`) REFERENCES `adtemplate` (`AdTemplateId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: we need to see those other 2 tables

Comment: Do you have 2 tables too? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db77b/1/0. The rule is that the object you reference has to exist.

Comment: I have two tables . I have edited the question. The create statement of bothe tables are given .

Comment: @SouravMukherjee The key is order of them. Show entire script how you execute it.

Comment: @lad2025 I did not understand you.

Comment: well, he is saying, the referenced would need to go first in a script. To exist prior to the table you showed first. So like this pastie: http://pastie.org/10600713

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imageadassociation` is the *referencing* table. Tables `imagelocation` and `advertisement` are the *referenced* tables.

The 2 columns in the referenced need to satisfy the condition:

From the Mysql Manual page on [Using Foreign Key Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must
>   have similar data types. The size and sign of integer types must be
>   the same. The length of string types need not be the same. For
>   nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation
>   must be the same.

and they need to have left-most indexes on them in the *referenced* tables. These conditions are not met.
In particular, there is no index on `imageId`

---

The display widths are not of importance (ie: int(11) )

---

Comment: Thanks it solved my issue . I changed Image Id to primary key in imageLocation table.